# I want to see only ts files in the search result in IntelliJ IDEA (WebStorm)

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

When I'm searching files in the project I don't want to see *js files in the result of the search.

How can I find only TypeScript files? Is there is some settings in the search?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify `*.ts` in the **File Mask** field.

Answer (score 0):

CrazyCoder's answer helped me. I just needed to add `*.ts` in the **File mask** field.

[image]